# Apache HTTPD: Allow users in htpasswd OR LDAP with specific group

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, ldap

There's a related question with an answer at [apache auth: combination of LDAP and htpasswd](https://serverfault.com/questions/111501/apache-auth-combination-of-ldap-and-htpasswd) but I'd like to expand on that.

I want to allow users if they are in the htpasswd file or if they are in LDAP and members of a valid group.

So `Require valid-user` from the other question is not strict enough as it would allow anyone from LDAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a valid AuthnzLDAP setup, it's possible to require ldap-group, like so:

```
  Require ldap-group cn=Administrators, o=Airius
```

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#reqgroup for reference.

It's worth noting that you can also require ldap-dn, ldap-attribute, or even ldap-filter.  The latter could also be used to require an ldap-group, like this:

```
  Require ldap-filter &(memberof=cn=Administrators,o=Airius)
```

..which is most useful to generate complex attribute-based requirements:

```
  Require ldap-filter &(eduPersonPrimaryAffiliation=*Staff)(objectClass=eduPrincipal)
```

---

Thanks, commenter @james-yale for the most relevant answer..

Comment: Or how about using `Require ldap-group` 

ref: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#reqgroup

Answer (score 0):

`require group X`, where `X` is the LDAP group and then additionally use a `AuthGroupFile` that defines group `X` with all the local users in it.

(Note: not tested.)

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible using different groups but the Users authenticated via `AuthUserFile` need to have a group membership too (via the `AuthGroupFile`). Then you can use something like:

```
<RequireAny>
    Require Group tehLDAPGroup
    Require Group tehAuthUserGroup
</RequireAny>
```