# Combine Apache authetication providers (file & LDAP)

Tags: apache-2.2, ldap, authentication

I'm trying to combine both basic *file* and *LDAP* user authentication in an Apache .htaccess file but I can't get both methods to work simultaneously.  It's either one or the other.

Here's my setup:

**.htaccess**

```
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider file ldap
AuthUserFile <path>/passwd
AuthGroupFile <path>/group
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ldap.<my-domain>.com/ou=People,dc=<my-domain>,dc=com?uid"
AuthLDAPGroupAttribute memberUid
AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN off
<Limit GET POST PUT>
        require group admin ldap-group cn=web,ou=Group,dc=<my-domain>,dc=com
</Limit>
```

**passwd**

```
test:jhhLuf0DfajXk
```

**group**

```
admin:test
```

When I change the limit values and remove or reorder the group settings, I get one or the other auth provider to work.  So I seems like a syntax issue on my part but I can't figure it out.

In all honesty, the *group* file could be dropped all together but I tried that and it didn't have any affect. So I'm including it, in case it has some bearing.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?  This issue is very similar to [apache auth: combination of LDAP and htpasswd](https://serverfault.com/questions/111501/apache-auth-combination-of-ldap-and-htpasswd) but not quite the same thing.

Thanks, in advance, for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve my own question.  It pretty much hing-pinned on the *valid-user* option for the *required* directive.

```
Require valid-user
```

Documentation can be found here: 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#require

As mentioned in my original question, the file *group* wasn't a requirement anymore.  Once I dropped that directive and the subsequent *required* directive that accompanied it, the *valid-user* option seems to have solved the problem. My working *.htaccess* file is shown below.

**.htaccess**

```
AuthName "Auth Test"
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider file ldap
AuthUserFile <path>/passwd

AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ldap.<my-domain>.com/ou=People,dc=<my-domain>,dc=com?uid"
AuthLDAPGroupAttribute memberUid
AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN off
Require valid-user
```

Both file and **LDAP** basic authentication are working and coexisting nicely with this setup.

***NOTE***

The following Apache modules need to be enabled:

- authnz_ldap
- ldap

My `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` includes these:

```
authnz_ldap.load -> ../mods-available/authnz_ldap.load
ldap.conf -> ../mods-available/ldap.conf
ldap.load -> ../mods-available/ldap.load
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [apache2 mod_auth_basic](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_auth_basic.html), one must be aware that the order in *AuthBasicProvider* is important if a username exists in multiple providers:

> Providers are queried in order until a provider finds a match for the
> requested username, at which point this sole provider will attempt to
> check the password. A failure to verify the password does not result
> in control being passed on to subsequent providers.